# Authorize docker container as gcp authenticated user

Tags: docker, authentication, google-cloud-platform

I have a docker container which requires a user to authenticated using `gcloud`.

Me (as a host) is authenticated using `gcloud` but that is not carried over to the docker container. How can I make sure my docker container uses the authentication of the host? E.g. if I were to run the container on a VM engine then I wanted it to authenticate as the service account running the VM engine.

#### EDIT

The container is running a python application and I'd like to be able to work on that application locally and interactively. I.e. being able to see changes immediately and it should be possible using PyCharm Pro IDE.

Comment: If you run your container on a Compute Engine VM with [Container-Optimized OS](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/), then the Google credentials (service account running the VM) are automatically forwarded to the container. Can you switch to Container-Optimized OS for your use case?

Comment: Thanks @norbjd. I can indeed switch to Container-Optimized OS but I'd still like to run my container locally for development (see edits)

Comment: Locally you can run your container and provide the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` variable in your container (`docker run -e GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/my/key.json [...]`). Be sure that your JSON key exists in your container. You don't even need to run the container locally, you can run directly your Python application (`python myapp.py`), as long as `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` is set to your service account key.

Comment: 1) When you authenticate with `gcloud` those credentials will NOT be forwarded to the container. This includes Container OS (COS). Those credentials are designed for the sole use of the SDK tools. 2) Do NOT store service account credentials in the container. This is a security disaster waiting to happen. 3) If you use a service account JSON key file, use a docker mount command to make the file available in the container and specify the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to point to the path inside the container (specified by the mount command).

Comment: 4) Advice: switch to a VM running Container OS and use a compute engine service account with the correct roles.

Comment: 5) However, this poses an issue running the same container locally and in the cloud. I would use #3 when running the container locally and #4 in the cloud. Use different docker run commands.